# Can I add leading zeroes at will when building an RLP-encoded transaction?

Tags: contract-development, signature, rlp

Suppose I'm building a transaction such as:

```
const raw = [
    new Buffer("0001", "hex"),
    new Buffer("23000000000", "hex"),
    new Buffer("21000", "hex"),
    new Buffer("0x00000000000000000000"),
    new Buffer("0xde0b6b3a7640000"),
    new Buffer("0x1234abcd")
]
const encoded = RLP.encode(raw);
```

Can I freely add/remove leading zeroes of those buffers without affecting the meaning of the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. RLP can't have leading zeros. It is designed to encode values in a shortest way, so redundant leading zeros make RLP not canonical.

What's more, transaction's RLP starts with payload containing size of transaction. By prepending anything there, you simply alter/overwrite the payload and make transaction undecodable

edit.

Encoding example:

257 is encoded as 0x810101 which is

> 0x80 plus the length of the string followed by the string

docs: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP

Comment: OK - but is that on the byte level, right? You can still have leading zeroes within a byte, i.e., 257 is still `00000001 00000001`, rather than `10000001`, corect?

Comment: I've added encoding example to my response ;)

Comment: Note: With nonce 0x80 is not appended until nonce ≥0x80 itself. So nonce of 0x0 is `80`, nonce of 0x1 is `01`, nonce of 0x7f is just `7f` whereas nonce 0x8f is `808f`